# Is it ok to let a Cloud Run process continue after a HTTP response?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I am scheduling a task in Cloud Run which injects data from a Firestore export into BiqQuery using the `bq` command line tool. This takes a while.

I discovered that the Cloud Scheduler Attempt Deadline doesn't match Cloud Run Maximum tasks timeout. It is 30mins vs 60mins.

I don't need to display a failure in Cloud Scheduler as I can use regular error monitoring, so I plan to respond to the scheduler request before the cloud run process has finished.

Is it ok to do this, or will the Cloud Run process potentially be killed by the auto-scaling mechanism after the HTTP response has been sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the life cycle container here in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract). In summary, by default the CPU(s) is only allowed to the Cloud Run service during the request processing, else it is throttled.

You can set the throttling to false to let the CPU ON on the Cloud Run instance after the response has been sent (and you will pay accordingly). If no other request is received on the instance, the autoscaler will kick it after 15 minutes (idle activities).

To prevent that, you can set a min instance > 0, like that, a minimal number of instance are kept up and running every time (and you will also pay for it).

Or..... Cloud Run is not the right service for you, maybe [Batch](https://cloud.google.com/batch)?

Comment: Thanks, in that case, it won't be a problem! I am using the same cloud run service to process a lot of tasks, and requests usually come in more than once per second. Also min instances is set > 0.

Comment: Also, the cloud run instance would not be aware of the 30min timeout of the cloud scheduler, right? From the cloud run perspective, it is still processing the same request up until the 60mins limit.

Comment: Yes, you are  correct

Comment: And on second thought I think the min instances might not guarantee that the instance stays up. Because the long-running task might arrive at a time when the instances are temporarily scaled up to say 8 and it could arrive at instance 8. Then that instance would still get killed when things are scaled down.

Comment: Also, batch looks interesting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you don't need to know the request payload or the query string, you might not need a Cloud Run service and create a Cloud Run job instead. Even if I must admit I am still not sure when to use Cloud Run jobs and when to use Batch.